# Setup Wizard tries to install to wrong framework version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, installation

I've created simple one line Console application for the 3.5 framework and was attempting to try out the "Visual Studio Installer" setup wizard project to install on a server. Both Console and "Setup Wizard"are for the .net 3.5 framework however when I try the setup.exe on the target server I get a message regarding 4.5 framework pre-requisites.

Visual Studio 2013 
C# Console application 
.net 3.5 
Windows Server 2003 R2

Any ideas where this reference to 4.5 is likely to be coming from?

Thanks
[image: Error message and Project screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As in the MSDN Forum answer:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/54e20ea4-ddfa-4315-9a04-57daa74b6952/setup-wizard-tries-to-install-to-wrong-framework-version?forum=winformssetup

"If this the installer project extension that generated an MSI setup and a setup.exe, then in the setup project go to View => Editor=>Launch conditions, right-click the NET launch condition, Properties window, and choose the relevant one from the drop down in Version. "